# Android app is not working frequently in Reliance JIO 4G connection

Tags: android, performance, api, error-handling

I have an android app which is working completely fine in WiFi and 3G connection of all operators except Reliance Jio.

However, I have found that Sometimes the android app is not connecting to my HTTPS web-services when Reliance JIO 4G connection is used, but the same set of HTTPS web-services are working perfectly without any delay when the device is connected to other service providers.

Comment: seems like that is the problem of your network provider.

Comment: @inderbagga did you found any solution to this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the user has an active internet connection before making the request.

use this method to check internet availability only make a request if this returns true, otherwise, toast them internet is not available.

```
public static boolean isInternetAvailable() {
    try {
        InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com"); //You can replace it with your domain name
        return !ipAddr.equals("");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

}
```