# Few Android Apps are not working/abruptly in Reliance JIO network

Tags: android, https, xiaomi

I am product manager for a mobile app that's working fine in WiFi(using hotspots as well) and 4G connections of all operators except Reliance Jio 4G. I see a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607173/android-app-is-not-working-frequently-in-reliance-jio-4g-connection) but there isnt any concrete answer yet.

If it helps, in similar condition youtube also doesn't work but if I uninstall updates it will start working but clearing the cache for the 'app under test' is not resolving the issue.

Anybody else facing issues of this sort?

Comment: "that's working fine in WiFi(using hotspots as well) and 4G connections of all operators except Reliance Jio 4G" - Have you tried implementing in `WebView`? Did you try opening the URL with chrome or the like with an active JIO 4G?

Comment: Sanjeev - This is a mobile app.

Comment: Did you got any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue. Firstly, check whether your API domain can open in browser or not. Secondly, check yours IPv4 on your android device, if it's not showing, then clear all browsing data and cache and restart the device, afterwards it should work fine as it did for me after following this steps.